# In Ember setup a computed on the controller but from within setupController in a route

Tags: ember.js

My application only has an application route, it manages to do without an explicit controller file. Infact I have no controller files at all, and want to keep it that way.

In my application route I setup a couple defaults in the controller that are used in the application template:

```
setupController(controller, model) {
  this._super(controller, model);

  controller.set('session', Ember.inject.service('session'));
  controller.set('environmentName', ENV.environment);
},
```

I now want a computed that will respond to two different variables changing. These variables will change in actions that bubble up to the application route.

So say they are `foo` and `bar`, a computed on the route itself would be.

```
someComputed: Ember.computed('foo', 'bar', function() {
  let result = '';
  // logic involving foo and bar
  return result;
}),
```

The problem is that this is not available in the application template. How can I 'register' the computed with the controller in a better way, and respond to application route actions changing `foo` and `bar`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though you aren't explicitly creating a `controllers/application.js` file, ember is still providing one for you (and you are setting properties on it in your `setupController` hook). You could set up your computed on the controller, not the route:

```
setupController(controller, model) {
  this._super(controller, model);

  controller.set('session', Ember.inject.service('session'));
  controller.set('environmentName', ENV.environment);
  controller.set('someComputed', Ember.computed('foo', 'bar', function() {
    let result = '';
    // logic involving foo and bar
    return result;
  })),
},
```

Now you should have access to `{{someComputed}}` in your template.

At this point though I would recommend explicitly creating a controller and moving this into there. Controllers haven't been killed off yet, and are still an important aspect of the ember design strategy.

EDIT: missed a closing parentheses.